# Prevent bridge connections from automatically turning on

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-bridge

Every time I boot Ubuntu, I have to first turn off both the bridge connections br1 and br0 to connect to my wifi. And there is no option to forget the connections. So how can I configure these bridge connections so that they won't turn on every time I boot ubuntu.
This problem arose after I used my mobile for USB tethering.

 
It's really irritating to turn the connections off every time I boot. Please help me with this problem, and also can you please explain why is it happening?

[image: Screenshot of the network settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turned out that in the file `/etc/network/interfaces` all the bridge interfaces have been defined. The `auto` keyword before the interface name bring up it up every time after boot.
So removing the keyword did the work.

[image: screenshot of the file.]

Use `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces` to edit the file.